# Why mysql_real_escape_string returns boolean?

Tags: php, sql-injection

I have wrote a PHP script to handle user login. To prevent SQL Injection attack, I have used 'mysql_real_escape_string' function. Everything works good till today. I have traced code and finding the problem; the line using 'mysql_real_escape_string'. I have change it to basic command following:

```
$username=mysql_real_escape_string('sample');
var_dump($username)
```

The output is:

```
bool(false)
```

On my local web server (WAMP) everything is ok, but on remote host the problem appears! What is wrong? (Host PHP is 5.4.12)

Comment: Are you sure that the mysql connection is opened before you call `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

Comment: Do note that `mysql_real_escape_string` is not the right way to [defend against SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1). Not to mention it's deprecated...

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

> Returns the escaped string, or FALSE on error.

It returns false on error;

Add the following line to the head of the file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

so you can view the error.

It is possible that you forgot to make a mysql connection, before using the function `mysql_real_escape_string('sample')`
Thats according to the first error in https://www.php.net/mysql-real-escape-string

> A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string()
> otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is
> returned.

You should know that there are better ways to prevent sql injection which you can view here:
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: thank you. That was the solution of my problem:)

Answer (score 3):

> Returns the escaped string, or FALSE on error.

[Documentation](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string)

I can't tell you what the error is exactly, but it's almost certainly this:

> **Note:**
>
> A MySQL connection is required before using `mysql_real_escape_string()` otherwise an error of level `E_WARNING` is generated, and `FALSE` is returned. If *`link_identifier`* isn't defined, the last MySQL connection is used.